# Error:Expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++

This is popping up as an error in my code. Please help!

```
bool validData(int id, float exam1, float exam2, float exam3); 
**************************************************** 
//Purpose: Determine id, exam1, exam2, exam3 are valid or invalid. 
//Input: id, exam1, exam2, exam3. 
//Precondition: id, exam1, exam2, exam3 are assigned values. 
//Output: bool. 
//Post condition: This function returns true if all data are valid, otherwise return false. 
//Note: None. 
****************************************************
{ 
    if (( id <= MAXID && id >= MINID) && (exam1 <= MAXEXAM && exam1 >= MINEXAM) && (exam2 <= MAXEXAM
    && exam2 >= MINEXAM) && (exam3 <= MAXEXAM && exam3 >= MINEXAM)) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Remove the first semicolon.   Also, it is better style to have your comments before the first line.

Comment: Well the code is a function so it technically needs the semi-colon

Comment: The semicolon is an error. It's not "technically needed" or anything. Function definitions don't take semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool validData(int id, float exam1, float exam2, float exam3);
```

is wrong, **don't need the semicolon.**